# Row and column headings on crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using the crystal reports 2008 version.

I need the column headers to stay on top while scrolling down the data. The column headers are present in the page header section. Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that this is possible in CR.  What you might have to do is export your report to Excel so that you can freeze the headers there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a group, something innocuous, and mark 'Repeat Header on each page' in the Change Group dialog.

Comment: that would the same as using the page header.